# Small thread ID on osx

Tags: c++, macos, pthreads

Is there a function that returns a pthread ID similiar to gettid()?
I tried pthread_threadid_np(), pthread_self(), but these are too long.
I need a tid that is at most 32 bit long.

Comment: The `pthread_t` is possibly "too long" in order to combat ABA ambiguities by not recycling ID's with too short a period.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem

Comment: why at most 32 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a strategy which will work on OSX and any other c++11 system which supports the gnu extension `__thread` (I have only used this because Apple's embarrassing branch of clang does not implement the standard `thread_local`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

static std::int32_t current_id()
{
    static std::atomic<std::int32_t> next_id { 0 };
    static __thread std::int32_t id = 0;
    if (id == 0)
        id = ++next_id;
    return id;
}

void emit_id()
{
    static std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
    std::cout << "thread id = " << current_id() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::thread([] { emit_id(); });
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [] { emit_id(); });

    emit_id();
    f.get();
    t.join();
}
```

example output:

```
thread id = 1
thread id = 2
thread id = 3
```

synopsis:

each id is a thread_local int32 which is initially zero (an invalid id).

The first time the id is required, the next available id is sequentially generated using the static atomic.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to maintain a static table of `pthread_t` values, and some functions to manage it. Your `get_short_tid` function calls `pthread_self` to obtain a `pthread_t` value. Then it searches for this in the table, and returns the corresponding short ID, if it is found. If it is not found, it allocates a new entry for it, enters it there, assigns a new short ID and returns *that*. You need some periodic way to expire stale entries. Every so often, the `get_short_tid` function can sweep through the table and use `pthread_kill` with a signal of 0 on each `pthread_t`. All those for which this yields an error are removed from the table. Your ID generation can just be a 32 bit wrapping counter; it's up to you to ensure that this is adequate that your application avoids the [ABA_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem).

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, `<pthread.h>` defines

```
mach_port_t pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_t);
```

which reveals the underlying unsigned integer id (32 bit) of the thread object, as known by the kernel. The values are usually pretty low, but the important difference from Linux `gettid()` is that `getpid()` and `pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self())` for the main thread do not return the same value.